# Distribution of current on a wire

Tags: electrons, electric-current, conductors

Imagine a cylindrical wire with current flowing through it. What paths do the actual electrons take?

My first thought is that the electrons only move along the surface of the wire; since that is where they would all stay, if the wire was negatively charged. But it seems weird that they would avoid the inside of the wire altogether, so this does not seem too plausible.

Comment: Does this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/490299/

Comment: In general d.c. current flows inside the wire. Only high frequency a.c. current is concentrated on the surface of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Excess charge applied to a conductor will reside on the outer surface of that conductor, but current in wires does not
result from excess charge.

There are very many mobile electrons ALREADY in a wire when a
switch is closed, it is not 'extra' electrons that are
injected at one end that conduct.   A typical lamp cord
wire carrying one ampere of current (18 gauge copper wire, one
meter long) has 7 x10^22 atoms, each with an electron
free to move within the solid (though still 'bound' in the sense that it won't leave the metal and wander away).

A  one ampere current delivers 6 x 10^18 electrons per
second, so it will replace the free electrons in that wire,
after three hours or so.   The 'extra' electrons that reside
on the wire surface aren't the important part, though
that would certainly be relevant if the wire were a
nonconductor instead of a metal...

The specific paths followed by conduction-band electrons are indeterminate; that band is a shared quantum state, and individual particles are not discernible in such a covalent bond electron state.